# In which n, do we relate O(n) and Spin(n) to SO(n) via a direct product?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, covering-spaces, exact-sequence

We know that the Lie group (here with real $\mathbb{R}$ coefficients in the matrix representation) --- giving that orthogonal group and spin group are related to the special orthogonal group via
$$
1\to Z/2Z\to Spin(n) \to SO(n) \to 1,
$$
$$
1\to SO(n) \to O(n)  \to Z/2Z\to1
$$

- It seems that
  $ O(n)=SO(n) \times Z/2Z,$
  if and only if $n=1,3,5, \dots$ is an odd integer. Yes or no?
- Do we have
  $$ Spin(n)=SO(n) \times Z/2Z?$$
  for certain $n$? How to show the answer if it is positive or negative?

Comment: Consider the case of $n=2$. The map ${\rm Spin}(2)\to{\rm SO}(2)$ is essentially just $S^1\to S^1$ given by $z\mapsto z^2$. (Imagine adjusting a rubber band until it is a double loop.) The kernel is $\Bbb Z_2=\{\pm1\}$, but $S^1\times\Bbb Z_2\not\cong S^1$ (they differ in their connectedness and number of elements of order $2$). Similarly for $n=3$ where ${\rm Spin}(3)=S^3$ is connected and has only one element of order $2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $n$ is odd, we do have an isomorphism of Lie groups $SO(n)\times\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\cong O(n)$, with the $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ generated by $-I$, the negative of the identity matrix (here we need $n$ to be odd so that $-I\not\in SO(n)$).  When $n$ is even, the center of $SO(n)$ consists of just $I$ and $-I$ and so is contained in $SO(n)$, and so we cannot have such an isomorphism.

There is never an isomorphism of Lie groups $Spin(n)=SO(n) \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ for $n>1$ since $Spin(n)$ is connected (it is the connected double cover of $SO(n)$).  When $n=1$, $SO(n)$ is trivial and so we do have such an isomorphism.

(If you don't know that $Spin(n)$ is connected for $n>1$, then note that to prove it you just need to check the case $n=2$: you know $Spin(n)$ is a double cover of $SO(n)$, so to check it is a nontrivial double cover, it suffices to check that its restriction to a double cover of $SO(2)\subseteq SO(n)$ is nontrivial.)